# ng-repeat splice showing double

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

For some reason, when I splice an object into my `ng-repeat` array, it doubles what I splice in and hides the last object in the array.

However, if I click the toggle hide and "refresh" the `ng-repeat`, it shows the right data.

Does anyone know why this would be happening and what I can do to fix it?

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.workflow = {
      flow: [{
        "id": "1334f68db820f664",
        "step_number": 1,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "1334f68e3f20f665"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "134967a5ba205f5b",
        "step_number": 2,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "134972c5b420e027"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "1334f68e7d209ae6",
        "step_number": 3,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "1334f68ef6209ae7"
        }]
      }]
    };

    $scope.insertStep = function() {

      var insertStepIndex = 1,
        task_data = {
          "id": null,
          "step_number": (insertStepIndex + 2),
          "tasks": []
        };

      //go through each item in the array
      $.each($scope.workflow.flow, function(index, step) {
        //if the step number is greater then the place you want to insert it into, increase the step numbers
        if (step.step_number > $scope.workflow.flow[insertStepIndex].step_number) step.step_number++;
      });

      $scope.workflow.flow.splice((insertStepIndex + 1), 0, task_data);

    }

    $scope.toggleHide = function() {
      $scope.hide = !$scope.hide;
    }


  });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div ng-click="insertStep()">Insert Step</div>
  <br />
  <br />

  <div ng-click="toggleHide()">Toggle Repeat</div>
  <br />
  <br />

  <div ng-if="!hide">
    <div ng-repeat="data in workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number'" ng-init="$stepIndex = workflow.flow.indexOf(data)">
      {{ workflow.flow[$stepIndex].step_number }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `push` to add item to your `array`? Also Is there any special reason to use `jQuery` `each`?

Comment: If you can pinpoint why `$.each` is causing this problem, I'll gladly change it @developer033

Comment: Nah, of course it isn't the problem, just asking.. please look to my comment again.

Comment: The goal is to insert an item in the middle of the array (after any specific index), not at the end @developer033

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem. This is a tricky but the simple part. The `ng-init` directive only execute once. So your assignment to `$stepIndex = workflow.flow.indexOf(data)` will not updated when you push a new data to the array/list.

So adding a scope function will fix this problem since Angular will auto call the function when it's returning value changes.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.workflow = {
      flow: [{
        "id": "1334f68db820f664",
        "step_number": 1,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "1334f68e3f20f665"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "134967a5ba205f5b",
        "step_number": 2,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "134972c5b420e027"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "1334f68e7d209ae6",
        "step_number": 3,
        "tasks": [{
          "id": "1334f68ef6209ae7"
        }]
      }]
    };

    $scope.insertStep = function() {

      var insertStepIndex = 1
      var task_data = {
        "id": null,
        "step_number": (insertStepIndex + 2),
        "tasks": []
      };

      //go through each item in the array
      angular.forEach($scope.workflow.flow, function(step, index) {
        //if the step number is greater then the place you want to insert it into, increase the step numbers
        if (step.step_number > $scope.workflow.flow[insertStepIndex].step_number) step.step_number++;
      });

      $scope.workflow.flow.splice((insertStepIndex + 1), 0, task_data);

    }

    // This is a new function which I added to fix the problem
    $scope.getIndex = function(data) {
      return $scope.workflow.flow.indexOf(data);
    };

    $scope.toggleHide = function() {
      $scope.hide = !$scope.hide;
    };

  });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div ng-click="insertStep()">Insert Step</div>
  <br />
  <br />

  <div ng-click="toggleHide()">Toggle Repeat</div>
  <br />
  <br />

  <div ng-if="!hide">
    <div ng-repeat="data in workflow.flow | orderBy:'+step_number'">
      {{ workflow.flow[getIndex(data)].step_number }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```